# Tests runs locally but fails in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, cypress

**The Problem:**

We wrote a simple test which only fills a textfield, clicks on a button and checks for redirect. On our local machines the test runs without any problems. In the pipeline the test fills the textfield and says that he has clicked the button, but nothing happens and the next condition fails.

**Our Pipeline steps:**

- npm install
- gatsby build
- gatsby serve -p 8000 & npx cypress run --record --key <KEY> --config video=false --e2e

**Specs:**

- Cypress: 12.0.1
- React: 18.2.0
- Gatsby 4.24.0
- Azure Pipeline running on Ubuntu 20.04

**Our Test:**

```
cy.get('#search-field').should('be.visible').clear().type(searchText);

cy.get('#submit-search-button').click({ force: true });

cy.get('#search-results').children().its('length').should('be.gte', 3);
```

**What we tried:**

- Increasing Buildagent CPUs and Storage
- Using different browsers (Chrome, Electron)
- Disabling Video generation
- Creating a new Pipeline (Windows)
- Running all steps from the pipeline on our local machines

Comment: You are using the `force: true` option which will always register the click even if the button is disabled, hidden, etc. Have you checked the submit button is enabled before clicking?

Comment: @jjhelguero The button is visible all the time

Comment: Being visible is one thing, being enabled is another. Clicking on a disabled button should not trigger any actions.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? @SebastianKoch